# Is it ok to end sentences with a possessive apostrophe?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, sentence-ends

I heard it's not appropriate to end a sentence with possessive apostrophe. For example:

> Jon has a great dog. I want one just like Jon's.

Or

> If you want your own, similar to Jon's, then trade me your raven.

Are these correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those examples are grammatically correct.  There is no rule against ending a sentence with a possessive.  For another example, see this Chicago manual of style question:

http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Punctuation/faq0018.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to look at "Jon's" in your sentences.

1. We can safely assume that "dog" has been omitted; thus although it says "Jon's," it's really saying "Jon's dog."
2. (I personally prefer this view.) Jon's is no longer a possessive adjective, but a possessive **pronoun**, just like mine, yours, his, hers, theirs and ours.

I hope this helps you see why it is OK to end a sentence with a possessive apostrophe.